# security review: chimera report - Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File Inclusion

Tags: security-review, chimera-security-scanner

I'm preparing for my first security review for an application which has an external web app.

I'm looking at the Chimera report and I'm seeing the error: `Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File Inclusion`. This is because my web app has static files hosted on AWS S3.

An example `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my_app.s3.amazonaws.com/js/js.js"></script>`

The report states that the risk level is low, is the something I need to resolve or something that can be explained away as I go through the review?

Comment: Why is the script on AWS and not inside SFDC ?

Comment: I'm doing data aggregation outside of SFDC, therefore I need an application hosted elsewhere. This app may need to integrate with another CRM so hosting externally was the way to go